# How to pass c# strings through p/invoke to linux/glibc wchar_t * parameters?

Tags: c#, linux, gcc, .net-core, pinvoke

I have a .NET Core 2.2 C# application that uses DllImport to pull in a native shared library on CentOS 7.5 (C++ extern "C" interface compiled with gcc).  Functions in the C++ library require wchar_t * parameters but these parameters appear to be marshalled as UTF16 strings not UTF32 strings as implemented in gcc/glibc.  Is this (my) programmer error or should it be raised with the .NET Core team?

Here is the highly complex method I am trying to call:

```
void wchar_tTest(const wchar_t *arg1, const wchar_t *arg2)
{
    std::wcout << L"wchar_tTest: arg1: " << arg1 << L", arg2: " << arg2 << std::endl;

    char *s = (char *)arg1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        printf("%d: %c\n", i, s[i]);
    }
}
```

I have tried using `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWSTR)` and/or `CharSet.Unicode` on the DllImport on the managed side to no avail.  These both produce similar results:

```
[DllImport("cover", EntryPoint = "wchar_tTest", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern void LPWSTRStringTest([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string arg1, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string arg2);

[DllImport("cover", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern void wchar_tTest(string arg1, string arg2);
```

The calls look like this (with `stringTest()` being a similar call but to a function with `char *` arguments):

```
string arg1 = "Hello!";
string arg2 = "Goodbye!";

stringTest(arg1, arg2);

wchar_tTest(arg1, arg2);

LPWSTRStringTest(arg1, arg2);
```

When the parameters are dumped out via `wcout`, `Hello!` becomes `Hlo` and `Goodbye!` becomes `Gobe`.  Output looks suspiciously like UTF16 when you go through character by character...  It looks like the `wchar_t *` skips every other UTF16 character (treating it as a UTF32 string I assume).

```
wchar_tTest: arg1: Hlo, arg2: Gobe
0: H
1: 
2: e
3: 
4: l
5: 
6: l
7: 
8: o
9: 
10: !
11:
```

Is there a way to resolve this without doing custom marshalling?  After all I have read it seems this should be a simple task but here I am.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given the amount of traffic I have seen with no good answers, I will post the short term hack I am using to resolve this given the constraint that the C++/native library side of the world cannot be changed...

I modified the DllImport to declare byte[] parameters

```
[DllImport("cover", EntryPoint = "wchar_tTest", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern void utf32Test(byte[] arg1, byte[] arg2);
```

and created a UTF32 encoded version of the .NET strings

```
string arg1 = "Hello!";
byte[] arg1UTF32 = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(arg1);
string arg2 = "Goodbye!";
byte[] arg2UTF32 = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(arg2);

utf32Test(arg1UTF32, arg2UTF32);
```

and voila you get the expected output strings and array contents

```
wchar_tTest: arg1: Hello!, arg2: Goodbye!
0: H
1: 
2: 
3: 
4: e
5: 
6: 
7: 
8: l
9: 
10: 
11:
```

This is hardly very portable though and of course fails when you run this on a Windows system.  I am hopeful there is a better answer.

Comment: Write a custom marshaler (see `ICustomMarshaler`) and have it switch between the two encodings based on the platform.

Answer (score 1):

The text is marshaled as UTF16 which is as expected and as designed. You need to either:

- Adapt your C++ code to operate on UTF16, or
- Custom marshal using another encoding, e.g. UTF8 or UTF32.

Comment: I don't think this is what the interop people had in mind, there has to be a cleaner answer.  Strings are called out as a separate use case they are so special. :)

Comment: Why does there have to be? Why do you believe that .net supports both UTF32 and UTF16?

Comment: .NET frameworks use UTF-16 internally, however the question here is how the native interops interactive with native libraries.  If the native libraries use UTF-32, it would seem that the interops would marshall to UTF-32.  Now I think this question is probably better asked of the .NET Core corefx people.

Comment: Feel free to submit a feature request to the developers of .net core. I just answered the question that you asked by stating how the library is designed and how it behaves. The fact that you don't much care for that design doesn't make this a poor answer. You seem to be shooting the messenger.